# How To Do Clojure Program?

Tags: clojure

I am learner, just now started learning regarding this..

Can anyone help me out???

Write a clojure program a function, most-frequent-word, which has two arguments. The first argument is a string, the second argument is an integer, call it n. most-frequent-word returns a sequence word(s) of length n that occurs most in the string. For example (most-frequent-word “TCGAAGCTAGACGCTAGTAGCTAGTGTGCA” 4) returns (“CTAG” “GCTA”)

Comment: so what have you tried?  if you have no experience with this problem _and_ the language, maybe it's easier to first start in smaller steps?

Comment: I am not getting any idea..How to start ...?? The are so many functions and I am bit confused.. so can you please give me a basic idea..??

Answer (score 2):

### Tips to start:

Some tips to try and get you started:

1. You can use [`partition`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/latest/clj/clojure.core/partition/) to turn the string into a sequence of "words". Remember to provide a `step` argument of `1`, so you get all the possible overlapping subsequences.
2. [`frequencies`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/latest/clj/clojure.core/frequencies/) counts how many times things (including sequences) appear in a collection.
3. [`max`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/latest/clj/clojure.core/max/) or [`max-key`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/latest/clj/clojure.core/max-key/) search for the highest values among their inputs. Use [`apply`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/latest/clj/clojure.core/apply/) to plumb the contents of a collection into them as individual inputs.
4. `partition` will output sequences of characters, not strings. You can turn those back into strings with [`clojure.string/join`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clj/clojure.string/join/).

I can get more explicit if you like, but for a beginner there's also a lot of value in experimenting with these at the REPL and trying to work it out for yourself.

### Edit: My solution:

Right, this particular step was a bit obscure. Since you want *all* the strings that have maximal frequency you need to do something a bit more than just `max-key`. The way I did it was to first find the `max` of the frequency values, then *filter out any key/frequency pairs with a different frequency* than that.

```
(defn most-frequent-word [string n]
  (let[freqs (->> string
                  (partition n 1)
                  frequencies)
       biggest-value (apply max (vals freqs))
       maximal-pairs (filter #(= biggest-value (val %)) freqs)]
    (map #(clojure.string/join (key %)) maximal-pairs )))
```

This isn't quite ideal from a performance standpoint, but seemed to have a cleaner separation of concerns (and hopefully be easier to understand) than trying to do both jobs in one iteration.

Comment: {"GAAG" 1, "CGAA" 1, "TGTG" 1, "TAGA" 1, "AGAC" 1, "TAGC" 1, "GCTA" 3, "GTGC" 1, "TCGA" 1, "TGCA" 1, "AGTA" 1, "GTAG" 1, "CGCT" 1, "CTAG" 3, "AGCT" 2, "AGTG" 1, "TAGT" 2, "GTGT" 1, "AAGC" 1, "ACGC" 1, "GACG" 1}

I have done using your steps and got this result. but when i use max key it doesn't work.It is giving the same sequence. I also defined a separate function to find max but dint get any. can you please help me out with this.

The max key gives max value for only lists. Does it gives for these mappings?

Comment: I used 
(key(apply max-key val (freq text))) then i get the result only "CTAG". but i have two max values.how to get both keys

(freq text)- gives frequencies of all substrings

Comment: Ok, tried to add a bit more details on how I handled getting multiple answers.

Comment: Oh, and yes, you can use `(apply max-key ...` on essentially anything that can be turned into a sequence. Maps (like we get from `frequencies`) become sequences of key/value pairs, which you can use with `key` and `val` or treat as a length 2 vector `[key value]`.