# Clojure program, basic programming

Tags: clojure

Can you help me out in below query. Many thanks.

Write a clojure program. Given integers L and t, a string Pattern forms an (L, t)-clump inside a (larger) string Text if there is a contiguous substring of Text of length L in which Pattern appears at least t times. For example, TGCA forms a (25,3)-clump in the following Text: gatcagcataagggtcccTGCAATGCATGACAAGCCTGCAgttgttttac. Write a function findclumps with four arguments Text, k (integer), L (integer), t (integer) that returns a sequence strings of length k that form a (L, t)-clump in Text. For example: (def text “CGGACTCGACAGATGTGAAGAAATGTGAAGACTGAGTGAAGAGAAGAGGAAACAC GACACGACATTGCGACATAATGTACGAATGTAATGTGCCTATGGC” ) (find-clumps text 5 75 4) returns (“CGACA” “GAAGA” “AATGT”)

```
(defn k-mers 
 [k text] 
 (map #(apply str %) (partition k 1 text))) 

(defn most-frequent-k-mers 
 [k t text] 
 (->> (k-mers k text) 
      (frequencies) 
      (filter #(<= t (second %))) (map first))) 

(defn find-clump 
 [k L t text] 
 (let [windows (partition L 1 text)] 
   (->> windows 
        (map #(most-frequent-k-mers k t %)) 
        (map set) (apply clojure.set/union))))
```

Comment: Post the code you've tried, the expected output from a given input and what problems specifically are you asking help for.

Comment: The expected output is  -   (def text “CGGACTCGACAGATGTGAAGAAATGTGAAGACTGAGTGAAGAGAAGAGGAAACAC GACACGACATTGCGACATAATGTACGAATGTAATGTGCCTATGGC” ) (find-clumps text 5 75 4) returns (“CGACA” “GAAGA” “AATGT”)   help me out in how to start and next basic steps as I have no Idea. I will try out and post my output and code here. Many thanks.

Comment: Since this question is essentially the same as the question you asked earlier I'm going to link them so they can be answered together. That question is marked "on hold" becase it needs to be edited and made more clear before it can be answered. Please edit that euestion to  include the clear definition of both problems you are trying to solve, an example of the input to each, and the expected output for each. After this edit, I will reopen the question so people can help provide answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Do Clojure Program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817366/how-to-do-clojure-program)

Comment: Using prev steps I tried and i got the solution as 

(find-clumps text 5 75 4) {"AATGT" "GAAGA")
but i need output as (find-clumps text 5 75 4) returns (“CGACA” “GAAGA” “AATGT”)

My code 

(defn k-mers 
  [k text]
  (map #(apply str %) (partition k 1 text)))

(defn most-frequent-k-mers 
  [k t text]
  (->> (k-mers k text)
       (frequencies)
       (filter #(<= t (second %)))
       (map first)))

(defn find-clump
  [k L t text]
  (let [windows (partition L 1 text)]
    (->> windows 
         (map #(most-frequent-k-mers k t %))
         (map set)
         (apply clojure.set/union))))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(defn find-clumps
  [text k l t]
  (map #(apply str (first %))
       (into #{}
             (filter #(= (second %)
                         t)
                     (mapcat #(frequencies (partition k 1 %))
                             (partition l 1 text))))))
```

:)